# Rounding a decimal value that can be divided by 10 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, numbers

I have an app where user puts a number, it can be any number from 10 to 10000, what i want its rounding up user written value to the nearest, in order to be able to divide that number into 10. For exmaple: user puts 13, app round it to 10, puts 87, app round it to 90, 231 = 230, 1143 = 1140 etc..

```
Private Sub Button9_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Dim value As Long
    value = 1003
    'Math.Ceiling(value)
    RichTextBox4.Text = value.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Err... `normal round (value / 10) * 10`?

Comment: Do avoid using Math.Round(), it converts to floating point and decimal fractions have no exact representation.  Integral values can be rounded with integer division,  `10 * ((value + 5) \ 10)`

Comment: @HansPassant : Not if you force it to use the `Decimal` overload by converting the input. ;)

Comment: do not use Textboxes or Richtextboxes for numeric input. Prefer, whenever possible, numericupdown control.

Comment: Hans Passat's - "10 * ((value + 5) \ 10)" works great. thanks